# How to make show all music option reappear in the Music app?

Tags: ios, music

I turned the show all music option off on my iPod, but now the button has disappeared and hasn't reappeared since. How do I make the button reappear? I've already tried restarting my iPod, and the worst part is that I can only see my music on my Windows 7 PC.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what you're seeing in the app right now? How did you turn the option off?

Comment: so i went to options and then i scrolled down to music, then i clicked on it and turned show all music off so i could get rid of the u2 album

Answer (score 1):

To show all music, you will want to go to:

Settings -> iTunes & App Store

In there, under "Show All" set Music to On

Comment: its still not there :/